# Unresolved external symbol when building in realease mode (LNK2001)

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, managed-c++

My solution has 3 projects:

- native C++ (static lib)
- CLI/C++ wrapper (dynamic lib)
- C#

In my native C++ project I have some image processing using opencv 3.2. My CLI/C++ project manages the communication between C++ and C#.

As long as I'm in debug mode, I have no trouble, but when I switch to release mode I get a lot of LNK2001 "unresolved external symbol" errors for the opencv functions.

For both, debug and release, I'm using property sheets for opencv and both of them definitely work (I use them in multiple projects). My native C++ project builds in both modes successfully but the build crashes on the CLI/C++ wrapper (this project uses some opencv functions itself).

I already validated the property sheets (corret libs, paths are set).

Maybe there are some additional rules I have to care about in CLI/C++?

**Edit**

I'm using C++17 with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: What's your build environment? Windows or Linux? I know on linux you can use tools like ldd to examine shared objects and nm to list symbols in the files. Not sure what the windows equivalents are. If the symbol is unused by the static lib then you might have to link with opencv symbols again on the dynamic lib piece

Comment: @Robb I've updated the question. I included the property sheets in both projects, so the wapper dll should link against opencv if I'm not mistaken